Derivative of matrix-valued function - general formula
Suppose you have a matrix valued function $A(t):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb R^{n\times n}$, and a real function $f(x):\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$. If we naturally extend the multiplication of real numbers to matrix multiplication then we can apply the function $f$ to matrices too, so that it is sensible to write down $f(A(t))$ (for example $e^{A(t)}$, or $A(t)^r$ for some real number $r$).
Is there a general expression that relates $\frac{d}{dt}f(A(t))$ to $f'$, $A'(t)$ and $A(t)$ ?
In simple cases (integer powers) it is quite straightforward to obtain a formula, and i am also familiar with some less trivial cases, such as the exponential or the logarithm.
Specifically i was looking for $f(A(t)) = A(t)^r$, and in principle i could combine the exp and log formulas, but it would be very ugly... So i was wondering if there is as general formula to obtain these derivatives, i really did not seem to find anything on stackexchange or in the litterature.
Related to this, i was wondering about two things in the specific case $f(A(t)) = e^{A(t)}$:

How is the formula $\frac{d}{dt}e^{A(t)} = \int_0^1 ds~ e^{(1-s)A(t)}\frac{d A(t)}{dt}e^{sA(t)}$ related to the Lie algebra formula for the derivative of an exponential map? It seems to suggest that $\frac{1-e^{-\text{ad}_{A(t)}}}{\text{ad}_{A(t)}}\frac{dA(t)}{dt} = \int_0^1 ds~ e^{-sA(t)}\frac{d A(t)}{dt}e^{sA(t)}$.
Using the relation from Kubo $[e^{X},Y] = \int_0^1 ds~ e^{(1-s)X}[X,Y]e^{sX}$, could one find the matrix $B(t)$ such that $\frac{d}{dt}e^{A(t)} = [e^{A(t)},B(t)]$?

Thanks in advance for any help in answering any of these questions.

The Daleckii-Krein Theorem
is your best bet

Do you have a reference for this so-called Kubo relation?

@Abezhiko eq 2.5 of https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1705306 , the author of this paper is also citing "Lectures in Theoretical Physics R. Kubo, W. E. Brittin, and L.
G. Dunham" for this equation.

@AlbertoRolandi. Thank you for the reference.

$
\def\Cin#1{\in{\mathbb C}^{#1\times #1}}
\def\D{\operatorname{Diag}}
\def\v{\operatorname{vec}}
\def\L{\left}
\def\R{\right}
\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\def\m#1{ \L[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\R] }
\def\mc#1{ \L[\begin{array}{c|c}#1\end{array}\R] }
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\vc#1{\operatorname{vec}\L(#1\R)}
$A recent paper by Magnus contains an interesting formula for the vectorized
gradient of $\,F=\exp(A).$
However, his formula actually holds for any analytic function $F=f(A)\,$ and consists of evaluating the function with a $\sf LARGE$ triangular matrix argument
$$\eqalign{
&{\Large\Phi} = f\L(\mc{A^T\otimes I& I\otimes I \\\hline 0&I\otimes A}\R) = \mc{
F^T\otimes I & \p{\vc{F}}{\vc{A}} \\\hline 0 & I\otimes F } \\
}$$
then isolating the $(1,2)-$block.
Adapting this to your problem, multiply by the time derivative of $A(t)$
$$\eqalign{
\p{\vc F}{t} \;=\; \p{\vc F}{\vc A}\;\cdot\; \p{\vc A}{t} \\
}$$
and reshape the vector into a matrix: $\,\Large\p{F}{t}$

I am not aware of a matrix/operator analog of the chain rule for a general function $f$. It has to be highlighted that it is usually hard to deduce general formulas for such expressions, because their properties depend greatly on the considered functions or matrices, that is why they are often handled on a case-by-case basis. Nevertheless, several strategies may be implemented, the majority of which are based on series/integral representations of $f$.
In the spirit of your question, the most general way to represent the function $f(A)$ is probably the Dunford-Taylor integral, coming from holomorphic functional calculus within the resolvent formalism, more precisely through the following identity :
$$
f(A) = \oint_\Gamma \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{2\pi i} \frac{f(z)}{z-A}
$$
Obviously, it corresponds to a matrix/operator analog of Cauchy's integral formula, where the contour $\Gamma$ encloses all the eigenvalues of $A$; yet, it necessitates a holomorphic function $f$, as well as a matrix $A$ with isolated eigenvalues, that is why it cannot be applied to any function in consequence.
However, while being quite general, this approach may turn out to be hard to handle in practice, even if the integrand is easy to differentiate $-$ indeed, one has $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} (z-A)^{-1} = (z-A)^{-1}\dot{A}(z-A)^{-1}$ $-$, but the contour $\Gamma$ will depend probably on the variable $t$ as well, in such a way that the Leibniz integral rule in two dimensions will be needed.
When the considered function $f(A)$ can be defined with the help of power series, i.e. $f(A) = \sum_n a_nA^n$, a more direct/naive approach consists in differentiating the said series, since
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} A(t)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} A^k\dot{A}A^{n-k-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \operatorname{Ad}_A^k\dot{A}A^{n-1} = \frac{1-\operatorname{Ad}_A^n}{1-\operatorname{Ad}_A}\dot{A}A^{n-1}
$$
formally, where $\operatorname{Ad}_XY = XYX^{-1}$. You may derive a similar formula when negative powers are involved. Then, it could be applied to your particular case, given that $A^r = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{r}{n} (A-1)^n$ thanks to a generalized version of the binomial theorem.
Alternatively, you may take advantage of a "gamma-like" integral representation of $f(A) = A^r$, namely $A^r = \int_0^\infty s^r e^{-sA^{-1}} \,\mathrm{d}s$ when $r$ is positive and similarly $A^r = \int_0^\infty s^{-r} e^{-sA} \,\mathrm{d}s$ for negative values of $r$, but it requires an invertible matrix $A$ with positive eigenvalues in order to ensure convergence. Then, you can apply the well-known formula for the derivative of the exponential map.
Despite all, perhaps the most common method when dealing with such expressions introduces a new parameter independent of $t$, as done in the proof in the wiki page you linked. In the case of $f(A) = A^r$, the exponent $r$ can play this role already, so that the function $\phi(r) := \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} f(A(t))$ produces the following differential equation :
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r} \phi(r) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} (A^r \ln A) = \phi(r) \ln A + A^r \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \ln A, \quad \phi(r=0) = 0
$$
which is solved by
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} f(A) = \phi(r) = \int_0^r A^s \frac{\mathrm{d}\ln A}{\mathrm{d}t} \, A^{r-s} \,\mathrm{d}s = \int_0^r \operatorname{Ad}_A^s \frac{\mathrm{d}\ln A}{\mathrm{d}t} \, A^r \,\mathrm{d}s = \frac{\operatorname{Ad}_A^r - 1}{\ln\operatorname{Ad}_A} \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\ln A\right)A^r
$$
where you can use your favorite formula for the derivative of the matrix logarithm. Actually, we run into the formula for the derivative of the matrix exponential $e^{rB}$ with $B = \ln A$.
Regarding your first side question about the two different expressions for the derivative of the exponential map $-$ by the way, please avoid to ask several questions at the same time in your future posts $-$, they are linked as follows :
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} e^{A(t)} 
   &= \int_0^1 e^{(1-s)A}\dot{A}e^{sA} \,\mathrm{d}s \\
   &= e^A \int_0^1 e^{-s\operatorname{ad}_A}\dot{A} \,\mathrm{d}s \\
   &= e^A \,\left.\frac{e^{-s\operatorname{ad}_A}}{-\operatorname{ad}_A}\dot{A}\right|_{s=0}^{s=1} \\
   &= e^A \,\frac{1-e^{-\operatorname{ad}_A}}{\operatorname{ad}_A}\, \dot{A}
\end{align}
$$
Finally, I am not sure whether the so-called Kubo relation might be of any help in practice, even if would imply formally that $\dot{A} = [A,B]$, hence $B = \operatorname{ad}_A^{-1}\dot{A}$.

The Kubo formula comes from quantum physics, where the time derivative of a state is proportional to the commutator of the state with the Hamiltonian.
